# create a function that converts a character string consisting of lowercase letters of the english alphabet to a number

Tags: number-representation, named-characters

I need a function that will take input as a string of lowercase letters and then output integers in this form
a=01
b=02
c=03
d=04
e=05
.
.
.
z=27
The letters must correspond with these integers because I am using them to represent an RSA cryptosystem.

Comment: The English alphabet has 26 letters, so how does `z` end up getting assigned 27?

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize the build in [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html?q=ToCharacterCode) together with a shift of `-96` for the character conversion and [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html?q=IntegerString) to get the leading zero for integers < 10:

```
toInteger[s_String] := IntegerString[ToCharacterCode[s] - 96, 10, 2]
```

E.g.:

```
toInteger["test"]
```

> ```
> {20, 05, 19, 20}
> ```

```
toInteger["abcdez"]
```

> ```
> {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 26}
> ```

To display the letters of a string together with their corresponding integer:

```
conversion[s_String] := StringForm["`1` = `2`", ##] & @@@ 
                          Transpose[{Characters[s], toInteger[s]}]
```

E.g.:

```
conversion["test"]
```

> ```
> {t = 20, e = 05, s = 19, t = 20}
> ```

```
conversion[StringJoin@CharacterRange["a", "z"]]
```

> ```
> {a = 01, b = 02, c = 03, d = 04, e = 05, f = 06, g = 07, h = 08, i = 09, j = 10, k = 11,
>  l = 12, m = 13, n = 14, o = 15, p = 16, q = 17, r = 18, s = 19, t = 20, u = 21, v = 22,
>  w = 23, x = 24, y = 25, z = 26}
> ```

Comment: `IntegerString` is `Listable` therefore you may write: `toInteger[s_String] := IntegerString[ToCharacterCode[s] - 96, 10, 2]` and btw +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing that out.